# Creating DBs on the fly for all my users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-simpledb

I'm building a Rails app in which I'd like to provide every user each with their own database to work with. At the moment I'm thinking SimpleDB due to its compatibility with JSON, low maintenance, and compatibility with AWS. However, I did notice AWS caps users at 250 SimpleDB domains which may be problematic. Anyway, I've never created an application which required dynamic databases that were scoped to users and was wondering if anyone was aware of design patterns/gems/databases meant to address common pitfalls regarding this application design.

Comment: Hey, take a look at this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16745/handling-growing-number-of-tenants-in-multi-tenant-database-architecture but be sure, if you store passwords, to store key-stretched hashes and to use salts!

Comment: Ryan Bates did a Railscast on multi-tenancy:  http://railscasts.com/episodes/389-multitenancy-with-postgresql
Sounds really similar to what you're trying to do with multiple tables.  He used subdomains as well.  Not sure if he's still charging for access, but it's a subscription to get in there.  You'll find more info on the web about this by searching on "rails multitenancy".